# How to interpret beta in VECM?

Tags: time-series, estimation, econometrics, cointegration

After running the Johansen test for cointegration, 1 cointegrating vector was found. Let's say the following cointegrating equation was estimated (A was normalized)

```
A              B            C
1.000000    -0.335218   -0.63412
```

A 1% increase in the A leads to a 1.34% increase in the B in the
long run. Is this the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is not correct. By only knowing the cointegrating vector you cannot be sure which of the series influence which other series, and what the effect sizes are. For example, B might influence A but not necessarily. To find out the effect of B on A, you would have to look at the estimated coefficients* in the VECM rather than the coefficients of the cointegrating vector (which technically are estimated before estimating the VECM).

(Your interpretation would be more related to the loading coefficients $\alpha$ than the cointegrating vector $\beta$, but even there the interpretation would differ a bit from your statement. Actually, if the coefficient vector above was the loadings $\alpha$, you could say that a unit increase in B leads to a -0.33 units decrease in A in the next time period.)

What the coefficients of the cointegrating vector mean is just what relative weights of the series are needed to produce a stationary combination from the original (integrated) variables.

---

* <sup>By estimated coefficients I mean the loading matrix $\alpha$ that premultiplies the matrix of cointegrating vectors (in your case there is only one vector, so $\alpha$ is a vector) and the $\Gamma$ matrices that multiply the lagged values of the first-differenced variables.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the response. The main purpose was to determine cointegration, and analyse the long-run and short-run dynamics. What do you mean by estimated coefficients?  The output gives me the normalized cointegration equation (where BetaA = 1)  and error-correction. From my understanding alpha is the loading coefficient (given by the error correction), and the normalized cointegration equation gives the Betas with one variable normalized (so it can be compared to Engle-Granger). Eviews gives the estimation representation with the betas (but not normalized) so they don't make much sense.

Comment: @Adrian, By estimated coefficients I mean the loading vector $\alpha$ that premultiplies the matrix of cointegrating vectors (in your case there is only one vector, so $\alpha$ is a scalar) and the $\Gamma$ matrices that multiply the lagged values of the first-differenced variables. The EViews output should also give you the $\Gamma$ matrices, unless your VECM has zero lags (which is possible). It is the $\Gamma$ matrices that give the short-run effects while $\alpha$ gives the long-run effects. Take a look also at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_model.) (bottom).

Comment: D(X) = A(1,1)*(B(1,1)*X(-1) + B(1,2)*Y(-1) + B(1,3)*Z(-1) + B(1,4)) The B values are 0.2, .04, and 3.9 in this equation. And alphas are given by the error correction terms. I don't understand what are your referring to. I have the values of Betas and the values of alpha. I thought that running the Johansen test already estimates an unrestricted VECM in eviews.

Comment: Yes I have a VECM(0)

Comment: OK, then there are no short-run effects, only the equilibrium relationship. You can tell the speed of reversion to the equilibrium by examining $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you. So my initial assumption is correct? EViews changes the signs of the coefficients when normalizing.

Comment: I was wrong above, your $\alpha$ is a vector, not a scalar. I also edited the answer accordingly. I was thinking about just one equation of a VECM, but for all equations taken together your $\alpha$ will be a vector. Which initial assumption? If you mean the interpretation stated in your question, then it is not correct as explained in my answer. This is independent of how many lags (if any) you have in the model.

Comment: I understand the speed of adjustment part. But I was confused about my initial assumption.